# Authentication Failed for iCloud IMAP Connection using Javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap, icloud

When I am trying to connect to an iCloud account using Javamail, it is returning an [AUTHENTICATION FAILED] error. This code worked for other non-OAuth providers as well (such as AOL, some Yahoo users). But, it is not working for iCloud.
Suggestions?

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", "*");     
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    session.setDebug(true);
    final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
    IMAPSSLStore store = new IMAPSSLStore(session, unusedUrlName);
    store.connect("imap.mail.me.com", 993,  <userEmail>@icloud.com, <non-null-password>);
```

Comment: What error are you gettting? According to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202304, the credentials for the incoming server should be your user ID **without** @icloud.com.

Comment: Looking at the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) might provide more clues.  You  might need to set the [mail.debug.auth](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/package-summary.html#mail.debug.auth) property to get the full details of the authentication exchange.

Comment: Thank you. @mazaneicha that worked.